# Unable to remove python and ubuntu docker images

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-image

I am new to using dockers,so i found these python and ubuntu images when executing `docker images` and i am unable to remove it using `docker rmi {image_id}`.

```
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete ba6acccedd29 (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
```

It was using up significant space,hence i was a bit concerned.

```
REPOSITORY       TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
docker_jupyter   latest    90708b9040df   28 hours ago   1.94GB
ubuntu           20.04     ba6acccedd29   7 days ago     72.8MB
testapi          latest    82e970c819ff   6 weeks ago    1.33GB
python           3.9       a5210955ee89   6 weeks ago    911MB
python           latest    a5210955ee89   6 weeks ago    911MB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to delete the other images that depend on them first

I think "test_api" and "jupyter" images depends on python so u need to delete them first

Comment: I see,i thought all these images are self contained,I guess i need to understand them more and the dates of creating the 'ubuntu' image doesn't match, so i was scratching my head.